# Proving special case of SAT is in P

Tags: algorithms, satisfiability, polynomial-time

Let *SAT-100* be the following problem:

**Input:** Any boolean logic formula

**Output:** True if there exists a combination of exactly 100 input variables that satisfy the formula.

This is the description of a problem that is apparently in $P$. (old exam question)

I have tried to design an algorithm but I got stuck, so here it goes:

```
Input: boolean logic formula F
    If(count(variables in F)) < 100:
       return false
    else
        # try all combinations of input variables
```

And here is the problem: building and evaluating all combinations of input variables can't seem to be polynomial because:

$$ { n \choose 100} = \frac{n! }{100!  \cdot (n-100)!} \in \mathcal{O}(n!)
$$

and this nasty factorial can't be bounded with any polynomial that I know of.

I don't think  the exam is wrong, so I must have overlooked something.

Comment: Hint: how many input variable combinations are there and how long does it take to check if each one satisfies the formula or not?

Comment: What do you mean by a combination of input variables satisfying the formula?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that
$$\frac{n!}{(n-100)!100!}<\frac{n!}{(n-100)!}= n \cdot (n-1)\cdot \ldots \cdot (n-99)< n^{100}.$$

Thus, your algorithm runs in polynomial time

Comment: this is just what I was looking for, thank you